# itextsharp pdf reader not reading pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-reader

I'm using `itextsharp` `pdfreader`

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
```

this is working fine for almost all the files, but for some file this is giving following error

> "Input string was not in a correct format."

I have checked name and location of those files both are fine. But still not able to find the issue.

Comment: Problem is in your `pdfTemplate` also you should share what `pdfTemplate` is of type...???

Comment: Nobody can answer this question without more info (such as the path that was used and the PDF that is found by that path).

Answer (score -3):

If the pdf with password protected will return this error too.

Comment: This is so wrong it's not even funny. The correct error message when trying to open a protected PDF is: "com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.BadPasswordException: Bad user password"